# Unexpected end of file in bash file

Tags: bash

When running a bash script i get the following error:

> ./hi.sh: line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Here is my code:

```shell
#!/bin/bash

#Remove unauthorized users

for line in ./unauthorized_users.txt; do

sudo userdel $line -y

sudo rm -rf "/home/$line" -y


#Remove unauthorized packages

for line in ./bad_packs.txt; do

sudo apt-get remove $line -y

sudo apt-get purge $line -y
```

Please advise me on what to do.

Comment: Is that the entire script? You are not closing your `for` loops with `done`.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: It might not be a good idea to play with a script that you don't know exactly what it does and `sudo`...

Comment: Also unrelated, please, please check that `$line` is not empty (`[ "$line" ]`), before you do `sudo rm -rf "/home/$line" -y`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not closing your `for` loop with `done`. Check [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs) for looping constructs' syntax:

```
for bar in 1 2 3; do
   echo "$bar"
done
```

Also note that your code **won't** iterate over lines of the file `./unauthorized_users.txt`. To read lines from a file, use `while` loop instead :

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo "$line"
done < your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Both 'for' loops need closing 'done's

```
for line in file; do
    echo "$line" # do some stuff
done
```

Other bash constructs (if, case, etc.) need closing statements as well